# Problems with subquery, trying to do a count from all tables

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm trying to do a count of every time 'txn_id' occurs in tables within my db

So for example in one of the tables:

```
SELECT COUNT('txn_id') FROM xr_txn_deal_party;
```

So there are many instance of 'txn_id' in different tables

I would like to do a query with subquery to check all the tables in the database, so I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT ('txn_id') from all_tab_columns where ('txn_id') in
(SELECT distinct table_name FROM all_tables where OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM');
```

But it brings back 0

Where am I going wrong with my query?

I have tried looking through oracle data dictionary for other ways but could'nt find anything

Comment: ... where 'txn_id' occurs in the table name, in the column name, or in the content of a column?

Answer (score 1):

Your first query should look like this (no quotes):

```
SELECT COUNT(txn_id) FROM xr_txn_deal_party;
```

It is hard to say what your second query is doing.  I'm guessing that you want to count the number of tables that have the column `txn_id` and the owner 'RGSWKF_PRGM'.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from all_tab_columns tc join
     all_tables t
     on tc.table_name = t.name_name
where lower(tc.column_name) = 'txn_id and t.owner = 'RGSWKF_PRGM');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes. When you use single quotes, it assumes txn_id as a string value rather than variable name.When you use single quotes, your query evaluates to fetching tables having tablename = 'txn_id',since you do not have a table named 'txn_id', your query returns 0.

```
 SELECT COUNT (txn_id) from all_tab_columns where (txn_id) in
(SELECT distinct table_name FROM all_tables where OWNER='RGSWKF_PRGM');
```

Regarding count part of the query, if you use single quotes, all the 3 columns of the below query returns the same value.

```
SELECT COUNT('txn_id'), count('abc') , count('xyz') FROM xr_txn_deal_party;
```